# Executing EF_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync from Interface

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I make use of the `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync` from an interface?

```
public interface IMyDBContext
{
    public DbSet<Branch> Branch { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I use the IMyDBContext I can make use of the Branch context.

```
_context.Branch.FromSqlRaw("exec foofoo").ToListAsync()
```

I am not sure how I would be able to use the `Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync` from the interface though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "execute from an interface"? Can you write some code even if it doesn't compile to show what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean in the c# 8 sense of providing a default impl in an interface?

Answer (score 1):

[`ExecuteSqlRawAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-5.0) is an extension method on `DatabaseFacade` so you have a few options. Here's a couple...

- Expose the `Database` property in your interface by adding this to your interface:

  ```
   DatabaseFacade Database { get; }
  ```
- Add a method to your interface that lets the DbContext deal with it. For example, in your interface add this:

  ```
   Task<int> ExecuteSqlRawAsync(string sql);
  ```

  And in your context, implement it:

  ```
   public async Task<int> ExecuteSqlRawAsync(string sql)
   {
       return await this.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql);
   }
  ```

  Note: You may need to implement the other overloads if you need them.

Note: You shouldn't have `public` in your interface since that makes it a [default interface implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/).